# Error al asignar a String valor de cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo un cursor para buscar la fecha mas antigua pero me peta al asignarle el string

```
Cursor cFechaAntigua = bd.FechaAntigua();

buscarFechaInicio = cFechaAntigua.getString(cFechaAntigua.getColumnIndex(ArticleDataSource.MOVIMENTOS_FECHA));
```

Esta es la consulta pero he hecho un log y me devuelve un registro

```
public Cursor FechaAntigua(){
        return dbRead.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(" + MOVIMENTOS_FECHA + ") FROM " + table_MOVIMENTOS,null);
    }
```

Comment: las fechas las guardas en la base de datos como string, getDateTime() , long, ó como?

Comment: Si el valor del campo "MOVIMIENTOS_FECHA" esta especificado como DATETIME sería buena idea lo agregaras a la pregunta, en este caso se usaría getLong() y este valor se almacenaría en una variable tipo long.

Answer (score -2):

Al usar en el query el método [**min()**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) obtiene el valor mínimo que es el primer valor no `NULL` que aparecería en un `ORDER BY` de la columna, el resultado por lo tanto sería un valor tipo INT.

En este caso debes usar el método [getLong()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getLong(int)) para obtener el valor del cursor ya que como es una fecha supongo el tipo de dato en el campo esta especificado como `DATETIME`!

```
Long buscarFechaInicio = cFechaAntigua.getLong(cFechaAntigua.getColumnIndex(ArticleDataSource.MOVIMENTOS_FECHA));
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.